# Hair particles with a force field stops at frame 100

Tags: particles, hair, force-fields

I have a simple hair particle system with a wind force field applied. As can be seen in this screen recording, the force field stops after frame 100:

https://youtu.be/fwV7PhLLGm8

[This is the file for review, if needed](https://pasteall.org/blend/b940bdbd4c204cc68916dd42fdc2b529)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [old bug report from 2017](https://developer.blender.org/T50390) about the same problem on the Blender developer site, where a user provides an explanation for it:

> The force field panel was designed with emitter particles in mind. ... The idea is that some particles of particle system will be force fields moving as particles to influence the other particles of the system. So, nobody really tested the use of hair particles as force field at its creation. Emitter particles and Hair particles are sharing same UI. And presence of this panel for Hair particles is probably an oversight. 
>  Emitter particles have a lifetime. On the contrary, Hair Particles does not born or die. It is probably the reason of the problem. Hair particles have a static root. You can use empties as force fields at same location to obtain same effect.  
>  In the future, emitter particles and hair particles will be separated. But currently, there is no developer working on particles.—ronan ducluzeau

Particles, physics, and simulations are all meant to be overhauled in the recent future [in a new node-based system](https://developer.blender.org/tag/nodes_physics/), so I doubt any changes would be made to this particular UI until then. In the meantime, I'd suggest creating force fields via separate empties instead.

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic. Could you point me to a tutorial or something explaining this technique? I can't find it. And when I active hair dynamics, force field doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not experienced in that area. Why not ask another question about that?

Comment: ok, thanks anyway.